# Pros and Cons of implementing dynamic data structures as array in C?

Tags: c, performance, dynamic-memory-allocation

I learned in university that implementing, lets say a list, in C would be more cache efficient when implemented as dynamic array of structs. So from what i understand its O(N) malloc calls vs (worst case) O(N log(N)) time complexity by realloc calls for maintaining the memory. BUT a "real list" of lots of data results in more cache misses. Is there a goto option, or does it depend?

Comment: I think "it depends" about covers it. It depends, to a large extent, on how you will most likely be accessing the members of the list: mostly sequentially, or mostly randomly?

Comment: This type of open-ended question is not well suited for an objective programming Q&A site like stack overflow, unfortunately.

Comment: If you can describe how to plan to access the data and what the actually data is, it'll be easier to answer with facts (like benchmarks).

Comment: Actually iam just fine with "it depends". Just wanted to make sure i have the right understanding of the topic. ATM iam working on a R/B tree for strings. Maybe i implement it both ways and benchmark on actual data. Its not even time critical, im just curious.

Comment: Dynamic arrays can be resized efficiently using a power-of-2 growing policy. This is what does the famous `std::vector` in C++ for example. This only require `O(log(n))` allocations and copies (and the overhead is linear to the size of the array). Lists can be optimized too using buckets to reduce the amount of allocations. In most cases, arrays are better. However, regarding the access pattern and data size, list may be better in some case, like when some items are inserted in the middle or for splicing.

Comment: If you want something more cache-friendly than an R/B tree, look at B-Trees.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it depends. Typically for small sized objects, then yes, storing the data as an array will make a lot of sense. For example, let's assume a singly linked list on a 64bit platform, in a worst case scenario:

```cpp
typedef struct ListNode {
  struct ListNode* next;
  char data;
  /* 7 bytes of padding */
} ListNode;
```

sizeof(ListNode) is 16, and then add in the typical malloc header size *(for arguments sake, I will say that's another 16bytes, but that depends on the underlying allocator)*. So for 1 byte of data, you're consuming 32bytes of memory at a minimum for each element.

If we assume a typical cache line is 64bytes, and we assume that the linked list nodes are allocated linearly in memory *(the best case)*, then each time we touch a memory location, 64bytes are loaded into the cache - enough for 2 data items *(and that's the very best case - if the list is sparsely laid out in memory, we'd only get 1)*. That's 32times worse than an array in the best case, and 64times worse in the worst case.

If however the data being stored is is either very large in size, or costly to construct/copy, then the cost of reallocating the array to insert an item in the middle may be too costly. *(in which case a linked list may win out)*.

Then of course, there are always halfway house data structures, e.g.

```cpp
typedef struct ListNode_X1024 {
  struct ListNode_X1024* next;
  uin32_t num_used;
  char data[1024];
} ListNode_X1024;
```

Essentially a linked list of smaller arrays.

Tl;dr, it depends on what your use case is.